# GET Value Display Without Quotes Or ;

Tags: php, get

I need the GET value to be displayed in this line of code.

```
$file_name = 'uploads/GETVALUEHERE';
```

I am not an experienced coder myself, so I'm sure this is very basic, but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: [WUT?](http://www.memecreator.org/static/images/memes/459010.jpg)

Comment: It may appear like I have no clue what I'm doing, which is 100% correct. Since I don't know exactly what I'm doing, I don't know exactly the proper name for it. I'm sure I would be able to find it on Google, but with what I was searching with, nothing came up.

Comment: Just answering the title, PHP is a language which each line has to end with a `;` and strings have to be quoted. So you want to "change" the language ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear at all, but maybe you mean something like:

```
$file_name = "uploads/". $_GET['something'];
```

As far as Googling a question like this, you would want to search for something along the lines of "PHP appending strings" or "PHP append GET var to string"...

Comment: Thank you very much! Don't even know what appending strings are, but Ill read into it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Please understand `$_GET` is an array that represents the query string. You also need a name of the query parameter to be read from this array. So if URL is:

```
http://google.com?q=foo
```

then to read GET parameter `q` you need to do:

```
$file_name = 'uploads/' . $_GET['q'];
```

#### More Details:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
2. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp